# How to zip a list of tuple inside tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a dataframe called `df` and want to create a list of tuples inside tuple like the one shown below.

dataframe:

[image]

Expected output:

```
[(('AK', 'Alaska Bible College'), 53.30776605944392)]
```

Comment: If you post what you have tried, someone may be able to help you fix/finish it.

Comment: `[((x,y),z) for x,y,z in zip(df.index, df['INSTNM'], df['PCT_CHANGE']*100)]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple answer to this would be:

```
output = list((x for x in zip(zip(df['STABBR'], df['INSTNM']), df['PCT_CHANGE'] * 100)))
```